# Warning: The plugin firebase_storage requires Android SDK version 31. One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: The plugin cloud_firestore requires Android SDK version 31.
Warning: The plugin firebase_auth requires Android SDK version 31.
Warning: The plugin firebase_core requires Android SDK version 31.
Warning: The plugin firebase_storage requires Android SDK version 31.
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to E:\Flutter App\cash_mimo\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
...
}

Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Neno.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1f04460684db0596892f5ab231ef0c5b\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Neno.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4bb066a21b46f5ea31ef8cd7876fc626\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 10):

your error log has already solution provided :

```
Fix this issue by adding the following to E:\Flutter App\cash_mimo\android\app\build.gradle: android { compileSdkVersion 31 ... }
```

Comment: but why isnt that added to the `build.gradle` file when we build the app

Comment: @DaniyalAhmadSE : thats depend on the when you created a new flutter project as its depend on latest sdk and they create project based on laetst android sdk

Comment: but i recreated my project and made sure that flutter was using the latest SDK, the exact version the warning message was showing to me, but it still gives me the same warning.

Comment: Can you share the current version of flutter in your system by running this command flutter docto -v ?

Answer (score 5):

The following plugins need CompileSdkVersion 31:

- `cloud_firestore`
- `firebase_auth`
- `firebase_core`
- `firebase_storage`

You have two options:

- Either you change the `compilesdkVersion` to 31 in your build.gradle file: `android/app/build.gradle`
- You downgrade all plugins mentioned above to a version which does not require `compilesdkVersion 31`

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to your local.properties file and add this line `flutter.compileSdkVersion=33`. Now go back to build.gradle file inside the app folder and change this line `compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion` to `compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()`

This picture should
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by local properties file?

Comment: Check the image above.

Answer (score 1):

Just update `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in your `android\app\build.gradle` file with the new SDK version.

#### Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your app without upgrading target SDK version for some reason, you can downgrade your android gradle version by adding below code to dependencies in: `/project_root/build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to update your compile and target sdk version as 31 on app gradle

Comment: Please, consider including path references, context, screenshots, or any other kind of resources in order to make your response more helpful for other users.